# Minimal form of rational, integer and complex polynomials?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Do all rational polynomial e.g $\frac{a}{b}x^n + \frac{c}{d}x^{n-1} + ... +\frac{e}{f}x + \frac{f}{g} = 0$ have a integer polynomial representation?

My thinking is:

$\frac{a}{b}x^2 + \frac{c}{d}x + \frac{e}{f} = 0$

$*bdf: adfx^2 + cbfx + ebd= 0$

Following on from that, what is considered the simplest form of a complex polynomial?
is it something like $(a + bi)x^2 + (c + di)x + (e + fi) = 0$

Or is there a form that all complex polynomials can be expressed in?

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}x^2 + \frac{c}{d}x + \frac{e}{f}$ and $adfx^2 + cbfx + ebd$ are not the same polynomial.

Comment: @LeeMosher could you explain why?

Comment: @LeeMosher Do they not share the same roots? Because that is all I'm concerned with.